# My ToolBox Show Multiple Copies Of The Same Control (VS2008)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, toolbox

My Visual Studio is all messed up and I have no idea why. See the screenshot below. The controls are repeated 3 times. I tried reseting the toolbox; still no luck. **The solution contains one ASP.NET Web Application and few class library. None of the projects have referenece to System.Windows.Form, still components from System.Windows.Forms are selected in the Choose Items dialog box.**

Is it only me or anybody else has ever faced such a weird problem?

[messed up vs toolbox http://img525.imageshack.us/img525/9171/toolboxissuelu6.jpg](http://img525.imageshack.us/img525/9171/toolboxissuelu6.jpg)

-- Zuhaib

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have your toolbox items in the on-disk cache or settings.

1. Close Visual Studio
2. Ensure no instances of devenv is running.
3. Go to Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft and look for Visual Studio temp files.
4. Delete the temp files.
5. Go to Users\\Documents\VisualStudio 2008\Settings and make backups of your settings files, then delete the originals.
6. Reopen VS.NET, you should be prompted to choose your developer settings.

Comment: This works also on Visual studio 2010. And sometimes is the only way to clean the toolbox.