# VS 2008 Toolbox shows multiple instances of the same control

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I have VS 2008 Team Suite on my notebook, when i create a web page and open the toolbox, i see multiple instances of the same control. Is there any way to fix this?

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283238/my-toolbox-show-multiple-copies-of-the-same-control-vs2008) . I tried the only solution posted, it did not work

Answer (score 2):

The toolbox is completely customizable. You can right click on the toolbox and click '**Choose Items...**' to add/remove things to the toolbox. It can get messy at times, which is why there is a '**Reset Toolbox**' there as well.

I found this article if the issue is much deeper then that (looks like article is for VS2005 on Windows XP, not sure how to translate that to VS2008 on Windows Vista)

http://accidentaltechnologist.com/microsoft/visual-studio/fixing-the-toolbox-in-visual-studio-2005/

which basically lists these steps

1. Shutdown Visual Studio
2. Locate the directory - C:\Documents and Settings\\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\VisualStudio\8.0
3. Delete all files named Toolbox.* (there were 4 of them)
4. Restart Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

You tried right clicking the toolbox and selecting **Reset Toolbox**?

Might be worth a go, havnt tried it on mine though - I have too many custom tabs to loose sorry **:)**

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem since the 2005 version (or even before).

Right-clicking and selecting Reset should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to delete the Toolbox* files I removed the .suo file and then I had also to run the following commands:

devenv /ResetSettings

devenv /setup

devenv /resetskippkgs

devenv.exe /InstallVSTemplates